# оформление поля "input"

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, html-form

Доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуйста: ест два input, один для логина, второй соответственно пароля, они сдвинуты вместе, как сделать общую рамку в месте соприкосновения, так чтобы все подсвечивания при нажатии и просто наведении курсора на определенное поле были по отдельности, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какие подчёркивания?

Comment: Всмысле подчеркивания?

Comment: Ну вы написали "...так чтобы все **подсвечивания** при нажатии и просто наведении...". Какие подчёркивания?

Comment: Ну хва закрывать-то! Для двух input'ов подряд в строке сделать рамку так, как работает border-collapse:collapse с ячейками таблицы. Всё ж вроде понятно написано...

Comment: @Yuri, не подчёркивания, а подсвечивания. См. ответ. Ну и outline ещё.

Answer (score 3):

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

input + input {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

input:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  border-color: red;
}

input:focus {
  z-index: 1;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type=text><input type=password>
```